# Outlook 2010 Anchor (url/address/link)

Tags: html, url, pdf, outlook, adobe-reader

I'm trying to link To a specific PDF page from MsOutlook'10 or MsWord'10, the #page=... anchor is particularly useful and works fine elsewhere. Unfortunately when I click [ctr-K] in Outlook or Winword, my links are re-formatted assuming a UNC path. The PDF file is located on a shared drive.

Using the "file:" prefix links will open a PDF in Adobe Reader (outside of the browser), and "http:" will open inside a browser. The issue is that I seem to need to open in a browser with the "file:" prefix in order for an anchor to work. I know the anchors work inside a browser. Outlook uses the Windows/Explorer Default Program (based on file extension) which always seems to open in Adobe Reader neglecting my anchor.

Is anyone aware of a solution, to link to a specific page or bookmark of a shared-PDF from a MS Outlook and/or winword link?

Common references:

- [mailermailer.com/...anchor-tags-html-emails](http://blog.mailermailer.com/tips-resources/anchor-tags-html-emails)
- [campaignmonitor.com/...anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/11/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/)
- [stackoverflow.com/...anchor-in-pdf-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427302/linking-from-a-web-page-to-a-specific-section-anchor-in-pdf-document)

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser, I don't know how to move it though.

Comment: To clarify from Windows Explorer I can launch [AcroRd32.exe] with [/A "page=7=OpenActions"] to a UNC path or i can launch [iexplore /chrome.exe] to a UNC with an anchor [#page=] but neither will work from MS Office, clearly in Word/Excel it's possible with VBA, but for Outlook that's not a solution. See also http://superuser.com/questions/463741/make-a-windows-7-shortcut-to-a-specific-pdf-page